# After using Redux are encourage to use this.state anymore?

Tags: react-redux

I am using react redux now, but some place does not need to use global state, just this.state are enough to do it. Does Redux encourage that?

Comment: Yes! Never put local state in Redux. 
Let's say that a toggle needs to happen within your component keep that state out of Redux. This article from Kent C. Dodds explains it really well..
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

Comment: So If I want to control modal visible, use global state? How if there is a both screen have modal, Screen A set modalVisible (global state) to true, and navigate to Screen B that also got modal, then the modal are automatically pop up when enter that screen, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you would include that `<Modal />` component in each of your screens and each of those screens toggle the modal.

Comment: Okay, I give an example, Im doing register, so after dispatch register success, set modalVisible to true, after that, click a button on the modal, navigate to login page, because login page also have modal, so the modal will pop up on login page, because they are sharing the modalVisible state, how I going to solve this? Everytime modal close dispatch a modalVisible to false?